# Read other application WindowManager(System Alert) Alert in android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, system-alert-window

I am building an android application where I want to read WindowManager(System Alert) Alert Text that is trigger from some other application.

Suppose there is some application like true caller and after the end of each call this application display some information of that particular phone number in WindowManager(System Alert) of android and I want to read all this information related to that phone number which is displayed in WindowManger(System Alert) using my application.

Is there any way to read or to get view child of  WindowManger(System Alert) Alert dialog trigger by other application.

Answer (score 0):

Think one way would be to write an accessibility service (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) and hook to some accessibility events. Maybe TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED?

Comment: I am using that but can't read other application system dailog.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS` in the accessibility service and listen for events like

```
    case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED: {
                AccessibilityNodeInfo nodes = getRootInActiveWindow();
                String nodeText = nodes.getText();
                String nodeContentText nodes.getContentDescription();

                // Also you could cycle through the children repeating the same
                // As an example only taking the first child, you could 
                // loop through or use recursion

                AccessibilityNodeInfo firstNode = nodes.getChild(0)
                String nodeTextFirstChild = firstNode.getText();
                String nodeContentTextFirstChild = firstNode.getContentDescription();
    }
```